# Implement sidekiq cron job from scratch with Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, sidekiq

I can call background jobs in my application by using Sidekiq gem. However, I'm trying to implement a Sidekiq Cron Job, which will run every day at 11 PM.
I have implemented the [official](https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron) doc of cron gem but it's not working.
Also, I tried whenever gem and still no luck.

Comment: You can add the steps you've done. And please describe where did you look for the luck) Take a look at this guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'd recommend [arask](https://github.com/Ebbe/arask). It is much easier to set up.